# How to get a summary from a saved search using suite talk Netsuite API

Tags: php, api, netsuite

Here is what is going on.

I'm trying to get a saved search, however, I'm getting the following message:

**We cannot return search columns for summary saved search**

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
   $search = new TransactionSearchAdvanced();
   $search->savedSearchId = '6429';

   $request = new SearchRequest();
   $request->searchRecord = $search;
```

Why would I be getting that error?

Thank you,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The error is because searches with summary columns are not supported in Suite Talk SOAP web services. In the help for **Advanced Searches in SOAP Web Services**:

> - If you reference a saved search that contains summary results, you    will get the following error:
>
> We cannot return search columns for summary saved search < saved
> search ID >

Comment: My next question is this, is there a way that I can get a summary of results from Netsuite via the API??

Answer (score 0):

As Brian mentioned, Netsuite SuiteTalk doesn't support Summary or formulas in saved search columns.
Therefore, What I would do, would create a custom field, make it hidden and do the calculation of the summary in a user event script After Record Submit (if the logic wouldn't harm the performance, otherwise, you can do that by writing a scheduled script to run nightly)
and in your search, you can reference that column and use that field in your search results.

Thanks.